# load highslide images directly into content div

Tags: highslide

Does anyone know if it's possible to have highslide.js load images directly into an existing content div visible on the page rather than the default modal box that loads content on top of the rendered page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such function in Highslide JS.

The closest it can come is an "in-page gallery," like the examples on this page: http://www.roadrash.no/?page_id=11

Comment: Thank you, with some tweaking that's very close to what we're after.